# How to handle multiple result sets from a T-SQL stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a T-SQL stored procedure that returns multiple result sets:

```
Select * from tbl1;
Select * from tbl2;
Select * from tbl3;
```

In my C# code, I have this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LIS.spData", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChargeId", chargeId);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<DataTable> dtList = new List<DataTable>();

            while (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataTable tmpdt = new DataTable();
                    tmpdt.Load(reader);
                    dtList.Add(tmpdt);  
                }

                reader.NextResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `while(reader.HasRows)` it says true, but I don't know why it doesn't store any data in my datatable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Aside: I wonder why [SqlDataReader.NextResult Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#returns) says of the return value: "`true` if there are more result sets; otherwise `false`." Perhaps it's meant to be checked?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is a collection of `DataTable` objects, the suggestions to switch to using an `SqlDataAdapter` to `Fill()` a `DataSet` are correct. (In modern ASP.Net, it's also good to get comfortable with `async` sooner than later).

But in the interest of demonstrating the capabilities, you don't **need** to do those things, and using `NextResult()` is on the right track. There are some other things in here worth paying attention to, as well.

```
// Stack using blocks to reduce indentation
using (SqlConnection con = new(_connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new("LIS.spData", con))
{
    // avoid AddWithValue()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ChargeId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chargeId;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // wait to open the connection until the last possible moment
    con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        List<DataTable> dtList = new();
        do
        {
            // No need to check rows or read from the DataReader to load a DataTable
            DataTable tmpdt = new();
            tmpdt.Load(reader);
            dtList.Add(tmpdt);  
        } while(reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

And here's a simpler version of the what the DataSet code might look like:

```
// Gotta love target-typed new expressions
using (SqlConnection con = new(_connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new("LIS.spData", con))
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ChargeId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chargeId;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataSet result = new();
    // No need to even manually open the connection
    da.Fill(result);
}
```

---

Finally, I want to address this:

> but I don't know why it doesn't store any data in my datatable.

The `dtList` variable is declared with a very small scope, and I wonder if perhaps it was re-declared later, rather than preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `reader.Read()`, this is done internally in the `dataTable.Load(reader)` method. Just check if there's schema available in the reader before calling Load method.
Here's how I did it (I needed to create an async version of adapter.Fill() method):

```
using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
                var dataSet = new DataSet();
                do
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                    // Check if there's a schema specified in the reader before loading it into datatable
                    if (reader.FieldCount > 0)
                    {
                        dataTable.Load(reader);
                        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                    }

                    // No schema..Skip reading and close the reader (it will only happen in case of executing a proc that has dynamic query and it doesn't have anything to return.
                    if (!reader.IsClosed && reader.FieldCount == 0)
                        reader.Close();
                }
                while (!reader.IsClosed);

                return dataSet;
}
```

Comment: This is mainly good advice, but misses the point of the question (dealing with multiple result sets).

Answer (score 0):

Simply send the results to a data set in place of using a data table. You thus can use the `.Fill` method of the data adapter.

A dataset is a collection of tables (data tables).

So, say this code:

```
    void LoadData()
    {
        DataSet HotelInfo = new DataSet();
        string sConn = Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("HotelInfo", conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Canada";

                SqlDataAdapter oReader = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                conn.Open();
                oReader.Fill(HotelInfo);
            }
        }

        // load grid of hotels
        GHotels.DataSource = HotelInfo.Tables[0];
        GHotels.DataBind(); 

        GPeople.DataSource = HotelInfo.Tables[1]; 
        GPeople.DataBind();

    }
```

So, the stored procedure can return as many tables as you want. Say 2 tables in this example (hotels, and say people that might be booked into hotels).

T-SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HotelInfo] 
    @Country nvarchar(100) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ID, City, HotelName, Description 
    FROM tblHotelsA
    WHERE Country = @Country
    ORDER BY HotelName

    SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City 
    FROM People
    ORDER BY Firstname
END
```

And now the markup:

```
        <div style="float:left;width:40%">
            <h3>Hotels</h3>
            <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server"
                CssClass="table"
                >
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:30%;margin-left:30px">
            <h3>People</h3>
            <asp:GridView ID="GPeople" runat="server"
                CssClass="table"
                >
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So a dataset is simply a collection of tables, and each table returned from the stored procedure will become a table of the dataset object.